# Ошибка ApiError: [29] Rate limit reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Хочу создать отложенный пост вк, но выдаёт ошибку. Время поста свободно.

```
def post(id, text='', pic='', sign=0, date=0):
    vk.method('wall.post',
                      {
                          'owner_id': id,
                          'from_group': 1,
                          'message': text,
                          'attachments': pic,
                          'signed': sign,
                          'publish_date': date
                          })
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\bot.py", line 133, in <module>
    post(id, text=msg, pic='', sign=sign, date=date)
  File "C:\Users\...\bot.py", line 40, in post
    'publish_date': date
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 668, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [29] Rate limit reached
```

Comment: Вот это прочтите https://vk.com/faq16098  Вы слишком часто обращаетесь к API

Comment: По коду, я обращаюсь всего 1 раз за команду. Не вижу ошибки.

Comment: По коду да. Но может вы до этого экспериментировали уже в этот день и превысили лимит обращений типа `'wall.post'`?

Comment: В этот день обращался около трёх раз, и каждый раз выдавало эту ошибку.

Comment: Вернулся на следующий день, та же ошибка, хотя в приложении можно сделать пост в этом сообществе с этой же авторизацией

Comment: Тогда не знаю, глюк какой-то в api похоже, напишите разработчикам

Comment: Написал разработчикам, сказали сменить токен, поменял, теперь всё работает